# How to Use User JSON file in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I need to know the JSON file usage in Meteor JS. First where the JSON file store in Meteor Folder Structure and How to get JSON Data using Meteor JS and is it JSON file save using the extension .JSON?. I didn't get any idea about this. Can you please give me suggestions about JSON files or is there any best references for understanding JSON files in Meteor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to **read** JSON data, you can use the [assets api](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets). You can do the following test in any project:

1) Create a file called `private/test.json` with the following contents:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"foo"},{"id":2,"text":"bar"}]
```

2) Read the file contents when the server starts (`server/start.js`):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  console.log(JSON.parse(Assets.getText('test.json')));
});
```

Here we are using `getText` to read the contents of the file (it assumes the file is located in the `private` directory). Then we are passing the JSON string contents to `parse` which will return an object.

Note that the file extension (.json) does not matter, however it is conventional to use it.

Comment: yeah,But how to read `text` only as you told above example.Can you please give me suggestion?.@David Weldon

Comment: The `getText` function just reads text-based files. So if you want to read a file containing only text, just remove the call to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Okay,But is not able to get data using reference of parse object?.@David Weldon.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to help but I don't understand what you are asking. :(

Comment: Means How to Iterate Data in Json file.@David Weldon.

Comment: If you do call `JSON.parse` then you have a regular javascript object which you can iterate however you like (using `_.each` for example). Just try using the code above - I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: The docs say that assets have to be static. Is there some way for me to load new files and get its text while the app is running?

Comment: @FullStack That's really a separate question. You can't use `Assets` in this case - you'd need to save the file elsewhere on the disk and use `fs` to read it.