# how to load json file in meteor server side test

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, meteor-velocity

My Meteor Server method calls another server to retrieve data first, cache in mongo db and then respond to request. I want to test my server code using Meteor with Velocity.

For unit test, I have a json file containing sample response from the api but I do not know how could I load that file to mock as api response for server test. Since it is server test, I cannot access `jquery` or `getJSONFixtures()` from `jasmine-jquery`.

How can I load that json file in my server test code?

**EDIT** As from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22007113/4281491) I do not want to put my test resource files bundled as assets in `/private` directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor: reading simple JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474675/meteor-reading-simple-json-file)

Comment: @sparticus what is `private` directory? Is it good place to store my test resource file?

Comment: The private directory is where you place server-side assets (not code). JSON files fall into this category. Just create a directory called "private" in your root meteor directory and place the JSON in there. Read more about private directories here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172215/meteor-private-subdirectory

Comment: yes the json file is definitely not code. However, there is some distinction between assets and test resources. When I deploy my code I would not like to publish my tests files. There can be multiple test resources, what you say?

Comment: In the private folder I would just create a sub folder called "test". You might be able to configure your meteor build to not include that directory, or do some fancy directory linking to provide access to your test resources without having them included in the build.

Comment: can you provide some helpful links not to include some files in some specific build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the nice suggestion from @sparticus.

This solved my problem:

1. Put all your test resource files in `./tests` directory. Mine is inside `./tests/resources/**/*`
2. For every gulp task to run test (`gulp test`) first copy them to private directory `./private/tests`. Then your test files will be available as `Assets.getText(<filename>)`.
3. Make sure you also clean `./private/tests` directory while you run any new tasks

This made me sure that my test resource files are not bundled during deployment.